# Calling a php file with jquery - session var is not read

Tags: php, jquery, session-variables

this is the code that I have to call my index.php file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$('button').click(function(){
  $.ajax({url: 'permiteCookie.php'});
  document.getElementById('div_cookies').style.display = 'none';
  return false;
})
</script> 
<?php   
session_start(); 
if (!isset($_SESSION['permiteCookie'])){
?>  
<div class="div_cookies" style="display: block;">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="cookies_botoes">
                <div class="cookies_bt2">
                <button id="button" name="button" type="button">Close</button>
                <a id="button" name="button" href="javascript:void(null);">Close</a></div>                  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    
<?php
}

?>
```

and this is the code that I have in the file permiteCookie.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['permiteCookie']=1;
?>
```

Problem: I cant access to the $_SESSION['permiteCookie'] in the index.php file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you called `session_start()` from index.php?

Comment: yes, it's present in the index.php .  I'll correct that in the sample code, though...

Comment: You are gonna have to do two separate ajax things. One where you initiate the $_SESSION variable and one where you generate HTML based on the $_SESSION variable. Or just include the permitCookie.php normally if you are just gonna do PHP related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The script is running before the DOM is ready. You'll need to wrap it in a `$(document).ready()` handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('button').click(function(){
      $.ajax({url: 'permiteCookie.php'});
      document.getElementById('div_cookies').style.display = 'none';
      return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

And as long as you're using jQuery, why use the plain DOM to hide the div?

```
$('#div_cookies').hide();
```

Comment: Tried this, still doesn't work. not even hiding the div works properly. Using firebug, I cant see any error in the javascript console. Any clue?

Comment: Check firebug, is the ajax request made? Does the ajax request send the proper cookie headers (both request as response)? Are you using COR?

Answer (score 0):

if I'm not mistaken, because session_start() affects the page headers, it needs to be at the top of the page, preferably the first line of code.

i.e. add this segment to the very top of index.php :

```
<?php   
    session_start(); 
    if (!isset($_SESSION['permiteCookie'])){
?>
```